How to stop default .azurewebsites.net domain from being indexed and appearing on Google search (ASP.NET Core 6 MVC)
I encountered a problem with my website domain. I deployed an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project to an Azure App service, and it worked on the free Azure default domain domain.azurewebsite.net.
I then added a custom domain purchased from another service provider, and configured my app to use this domain. It works well without any other problem.
But I found that both the last default domain and custom domain appear in Google search.
I tried to add 301 redirection and robots.txt to redirect the request to last domain to custom domain, but the problem continues.
I want to show only the custom domain on search engine.
I checked the following question related to wordpress, but no help.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1318669/how-to-stop-default-azurewebsites-net-domain-from
I hope someone help me with great heart. Any advice would be welcome.
Thanks in advance.
I checked QA from here and Azure Community for the solution, but still couldn't find.

“ I tried to add 301 redirection and robots.txt to redirect the request”, so for how long? It takes weeks or even mouths to take effect so you have to be patient.

I know it and it's so long time from I configured the setting.

More than a month passed.

SEO is not very much on topic of this site. Try https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or hire SEO consultants.

I'm using asp.net core mvc 6 and don't have the web.config file.
If I add it manually, does it work?

Hi max ray, please find the web.config in kudu site, and change the settings like this.

Because asp.net core is cross-platform, web.config is not included by default. We can of course create it in the project and include it when publishing, so that this file will be included every time it is published to the windows platform.

Looking forward to your reply, wondering if web.config is useful to you?

Thank you. I'll try this approach now.

Do I need to change the pattern for my default domain from the following?


@maxray Yes, you should change it to your default domain name.

@JasonPan
Thank you very much. This approach works very well.
Please make an answer with this content.
I'll accept you.
Thanks again.

Thanks for your reply, I will also post my answer in QA platform, have a nice day.

We can implement this feature by following settings. Please replace the default domain name and use yours.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <!--<rules>-->
          <!-- Block access to Azure default domain names -->
          <!--<rule name="Block Azure Default Domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^webapplication220240628111356\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" statusReason="Not Found" statusDescription="This page is not available." />
          </rule>
        </rules>-->
        <outboundRules>
          <!-- Add X-Robots-Tag header -->
          <rule name="Noindex Azure Default Domain" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X_ROBOTS_TAG" pattern=".*" />
            <conditions>
              <!-- if request from default domain -->
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^webapplication220240628111356\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <!-- set X-Robots-Tag  -->
            <action type="Rewrite" value="noindex, nofollow" />
          </rule>
          <!-- Precondition to check if response is HTML -->
          <preConditions>
            <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml">
              <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
            </preCondition>
          </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
      </rewrite>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>


In my experience, we don't have to replace the default domain name.
It's only the pattern, I think.
Works well, thanks Jason.
